# cmd/bat "switch". does not change the variable in ELSE

Tags: cmd.exe

I am trying to make a parameter switch in the menu, but it does not change in the opposite direction.
It seems everything is elementary, but does not work.

```
set x=900
:1
cls & echo %x%
choice /c 12 /n
if %ErrorLevel%==1 (if x==0 (set x=1 & goto 1) else (set x=0 & goto 1))
if %ErrorLevel%==2 (if x==900 (set x=2 & goto 1))
goto 1
```

Comment: You should use delayed expansion https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: @montonero That's not the problem, to compare a variables content you have to do so: x will never be equal to 0 or 900, `%x%` might be.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
set x=900 
:1 cls & echo %x%
 choice /c 12 /n
   if %ErrorLevel%==1 (if x==0 (set x=1 & goto 1) else (set x=0 & goto 1))
   if %ErrorLevel%==2 (if x==900 (set x=2 & goto 1) else goto 1)
```

I added `else` and moved a `)` on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

it's Magic. Banal mistake.

```
if x==0
```

It does not compare the value of the variable, but simply x.
That's how it works and works as intended:

`if %x%==0` ...
However, it does not work in my full example (also after ELSE. Flies out):

```
cd %userprofile%/desktop/ffmpeg
set цикл==for %%a in ("in\*.*") do (

set va=
set vat=только аудио

:Гменю
echo    =================================================================
echo    [7]-Скачать видео по ссылке
echo    [8]-Скачать видео списоком
echo    [9]-Переключить режим скачивания (бычный/аудио). Сейчас активен режим: %vat%
echo %va%
echo    [0]-Выход
echo    =================================================================
choice /c 1234567890 /n /m "Нажми на клавиатуре клавишу, согласно пункту меню:"

if %ErrorLevel%==2 (goto ручныенастройки)
if %ErrorLevel%==9 (if %vat%==обычный (set vat=только аудио & set va=--extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality & cls & goto Гменю) else if %vat%==только аудио (set vat=обычный & set va=88 & cls & goto Гменю))
```

Here the “switch” works perfectly:

```
set x=900
:1
cls 
echo bla-bla-bla u select to: %x%
echo ============
choice /c 12 /n
if %ErrorLevel%==1 (if %x%==0 (set x=1 & goto 1) else set x=0 & goto 1)
if %ErrorLevel%==2 (if %x%==2 (set x=3 & goto 1) else set x=2 & goto 1)
goto 1
```